# How to insert line break within OPENXML spreadsheet cell?

Tags: c#, cell, openxml, spreadsheet, line-breaks

I'm currently using something like this to insert inline string in a cell :

```
new Cell() 
{ 
    CellReference = "E2", 
    StyleIndex = (UInt32Value)4U, 
    DataType = CellValues.InlineString, 
    InlineString = new InlineString(new Text( "some text")) 
}
```

But `\n` doesn't work to insert line break, how can i do this?

---

The response

```
new Cell(
         new CellValue("string \n string")
        ) 
    { 
        CellReference = "E2", 
        StyleIndex = (UInt32Value)4U, 
        DataType = CellValues.String         
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try CellValues.String instead of CellValues.InlineString.

Comment: Although technically CellValues.String is only for formulas. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468783/what-is-the-difference-between-cellvalues-inlinestring-and-cellvalues-string-in

Answer (score 14):

You need to do two things:

**1.)** Mark the cell as "Wrapped Text".  You can do this in the spreadsheet by hand if you are using an existing spreadsheet as your template.  Just right-click on the cell(s) and select "*Format Cells..*", click on the "*Alignment*" tab and check the "*Wrap Text*" checkbox.
**OR...** You can set the CellFormat programmatically.  If you have a CellFormat object called "***cf*** ", you would do something like this:

```
cf.ApplyAlignment = true;//Set this so that Excel knows to use it.
if (cf.Alignment == null)//If no pre-existing Alignment, then add it.
  cf.Alignment = new Alignment() { WrapText = true };
Alignment a = cf.Alignment;
if (a.WrapText == null || a.WrapText.Value == false)
  a.WrapText = new BooleanValue(true);//Update pre-existing Alignment.
```

**2.)** You shouldn't use "\n", instead you should be using the standard carriage-return + line-feed combination: "\r\n"
If you are mixing the two (i.e. "\n" without the preceeding "\r" and "\r\n"), this should fix it before populating the cell value:

```
sHeaderText = sHeaderText.Replace("\r\n", "\n").Replace("\n", "\r\n");
```

I, myself, do not use *CellValues.String* or even *CellValues.InlineString*.
Instead I build my text cells using *CellValues.SharedString* (just like Excel does).
For Bool I use "*CellValues.Boolean*", and for all others (numerics and dates) I do not set the cell's *DataType* to anything - because that is what Excel does when I look at the markup it creates.

Comment: How do you apply the `CellFormat` object or `Alignment` object to a given cell?

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I just get an error on the line with \r\n and excel won't open the sheet with the text saying it is corrupted