# What is the difference between CellValues.InlineString and CellValues.String in OpenXML?

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am trying to write some code to generate an Excel spreadsheet and I am not sure what the difference between **CellValues.InlineString** and **CellValues.String** to insert text on the cells.

Shall I use this:

```
private void UpdateCellTextValue(Cell cell,string cellValue)
{
    InlineString inlineString = new InlineString();
    Text cellValueText = new Text { Text = cellValue };
    inlineString.AppendChild(cellValueText);

    cell.DataType = CellValues.InlineString;
    cell.AppendChild(inlineString); 
}
```

this

```
private void UpdateCellTextValue(Cell cell, string cellValue)
{
    cell.CellValue = new CellValue(cellValue);
    cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);
}
```

or just this (InsertSharedStringItem returns the Id of the newly inserted shared string item)

```
private void SetCellSharedTextValue(Cell cell,string cellValue)
{        
    int stringId = InsertSharedStringItem(cellValue);
    cell.CellValue = new CellValue(stringId.ToString());
    cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.SharedString);
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the documentation at [18.18.11 ST_CellType](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-376,%20Third%20Edition,%20Part%201%20-%20Fundamentals%20And%20Markup%20Language%20Reference.zip):

> str (String) Cell containing a formula
>   string.

You will only want to use the CellValues.String when you are inserting a formula in the cell. Here is how the XML should look:

```
<x:c r="C6" s="1" vm="15" t="str">
   <x:f>CUBEVALUE("xlextdat9 Adventure Works",C$5,$A6)</x:f>
   <x:v>2838512.355</x:v>
</x:c>
```

`CellValues.InlineString` should only be used if you don't want to store the string in the `SharedStringTable`. Then anything you mark as an `inlineString` will be treated as rich text. Although note that when you use `CellValues.InlineString` that your text must be surounded by a text element and `<is>` tag:

```
<x:c r="B2" t="inlineStr">
   <is><t>test string</t></is>
</c>
```

Comment: Please where is the link of the documentation you quoted from?

Comment: I updated the answer with the link to download the pdf for the open xml spec. You can search in there or reference this microsoft link for the examples http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.cell%28v=office.14%29.aspx