# OpenXML Spreadsheet- Preserve space before or after the value when writing a cell value

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk, spreadsheetml

I am using OPENXML SDK 2.0 to stream the spread sheet file. The source data is come from data table and writing this to Spreadsheet using openxml. If there is a one of the column data of a data table has **"      Treshold%"** (this text has tab space on it preceding) and the same being written excel but which is writing it to **"Treshold%"** in excel cell and removing the tab space.

I am using the code as below. Using `workSheetWriter.PasteText` and `workSheetWriter.PasteValue` methods.

```cs
WorksheetWriter workSheetWriter = new WorksheetWriter(spreadSheet, workSheet);

int intValue = 0;
if (strValue.Contains("$"))
{
    strValue = strValue.Replace("$", "");
    strValue = strValue.Replace(",", "");

    workSheetWriter.PasteValue(cellLocation, strValue, CellValues.Number);
}
else if (int.TryParse(strValue, out intValue))
{
    workSheetWriter.PasteValue(cellLocation, strValue, CellValues.Number);
}
else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue))
{
    workSheetWriter.PasteText(cellLocation, strValue);
}
else
{
    workSheetWriter.PasteText(cellLocation, strValue);
}
```

Please help on this. How can write the value which a tab space in the begining (    Treshold%) into excel cell as same format ?

Answer (score 6):

> I am using OPENXML SDK 2.0

Since there is no `workSheetWriter` class in *OpenXML SDK 2.0*, I guess you are using this library: [Simple OOXML](http://simpleooxml.codeplex.com/)

I don't use this library but,

- from the code I see in browserCode on CodePlex,
- according to my testing,
- and according to this SO question [What is the difference between CellValues.InlineString and CellValues.String in OpenXML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468783/what-is-the-difference-between-cellvalues-inlinestring-and-cellvalues-string-in),

I think **you can't** by using these methods, since the `.PastText` and `.PasteValue` methods are storing text by using `CellValues.String` and `CellValue`, and this causes that the space is ignored:

```
{
    cell.CellValue = new CellValue(value);
    cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(type);
}
```

By using *OPENXML SDK 2.0* only, I am able to accomplish what you want (preserve space) by using `CellValues.InlineString` type, `InlineString` and `Text` class:

```
Text text1 = new Text
{
    Text = " Text with space at beginning",
    Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve
};

cell.InlineString = new InlineString(text1);
cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.InlineString);
```

Comment: If anyone desires another example with more code: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wriju/2016/03/13/open-xml-create-excel-from-scratch.  NOTE: this example does not have the "Preserve" setting set, which is required to keep spacing.  You would need to modify the line "Text t = new Text();" to "Text t = new Text() { Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve };"