# error while exporting to excel data : ' ', hexadecimal value 0x07, is an invalid character using c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have got strange problem when I try to export data in kendo ui grid to excel .....

**Error :**

```
  An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Xml.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: ' ', hexadecimal value 0x07, is an invalid character.
```

and the below  method I was used for export to excel

```
  private static void WriteDataTableToExcelWorksheet(DataTable dt, WorksheetPart worksheetPart)
  {
        OpenXmlWriter writer = OpenXmlWriter.Create(worksheetPart);
        writer.WriteStartElement(new Worksheet());
        writer.WriteStartElement(new SheetData());

        string cellValue = "";

        int numberOfColumns = dt.Columns.Count;
        bool[] IsNumericColumn = new bool[numberOfColumns];

        string[] excelColumnNames = new string[numberOfColumns];
        for (int n = 0; n < numberOfColumns; n++)
            excelColumnNames[n] = GetExcelColumnName(n);

        uint rowIndex = 1;

        writer.WriteStartElement(new Row { RowIndex = rowIndex });
        for (int colInx = 0; colInx < numberOfColumns; colInx++)
        {
            DataColumn col = dt.Columns[colInx];
            AppendTextCell(excelColumnNames[colInx] + "1", col.ColumnName, ref writer);
            IsNumericColumn[colInx] = (col.DataType.FullName == "System.Decimal") || (col.DataType.FullName == "System.Int32") || (col.DataType.FullName == "System.Double") || (col.DataType.FullName == "System.Single");
        }
        writer.WriteEndElement();   

        double cellNumericValue = 0;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {

            ++rowIndex;

            writer.WriteStartElement(new Row { RowIndex = rowIndex });

            for (int colInx = 0; colInx < numberOfColumns; colInx++)
            {
                cellValue = dr.ItemArray[colInx].ToString();

                if (IsNumericColumn[colInx])
                {

                    cellNumericValue = 0;
                    if (double.TryParse(cellValue, out cellNumericValue))
                    {
                        cellValue = cellNumericValue.ToString();
                        AppendNumericCell(excelColumnNames[colInx] + rowIndex.ToString(), cellValue, ref writer);
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    AppendTextCell(excelColumnNames[colInx] + rowIndex.ToString(), cellValue, ref writer);
                }
            }
            writer.WriteEndElement(); 
        }
        writer.WriteEndElement(); 
        writer.WriteEndElement(); 

        writer.Close();
   }

   private static void AppendTextCell(string cellReference, string cellStringValue, ref OpenXmlWriter writer)
   {

        writer.WriteElement(new Cell { CellValue = new CellValue(cellStringValue), CellReference = cellReference, DataType = CellValues.String });
   }
```

in the below mentioned method I am getting above exception error..

```
  private static void AppendTextCell(string cellReference, string cellStringValue, ref OpenXmlWriter writer)
  {           
       writer.WriteElement(new Cell { CellValue = new CellValue(cellStringValue), CellReference = cellReference, DataType = CellValues.String });
  }
```

would any one please help on how to overcome this error while exporting to excel data ....

Many thanks in advance..

Comment: You should use `>` to format errors and get your code left justified.

Comment: Maybe you need to use CellValues.InlineString as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468783/what-is-the-difference-between-cellvalues-inlinestring-and-cellvalues-string-in

Comment: @MikeHixson sorry inline string also I am getting same problem....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XML can handle just about any character, but there are ranges, control codes and such, that it won't.

Your best bet, if you can't get them to fix their output, is to sanitize the raw data you're receiving. You need replace illegal characters with the character reference format you noted.

There are a lot of symbols which can't be in xml code. For replace them we can use Reqex.Replace

```
static string ReplaceHexadecimalSymbols(string txt)
{
   string r = "[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x26]";
   return Regex.Replace(txt, r,"",RegexOptions.Compiled);
}
```

Comment: hmm thanks .. where I need to use this replacement in my code

Comment: invoke this function where you write data to excel to replace string that you want to insert in excel.

Comment: like this........ cellValue = ReplaceHexadecimalSymbols (dr.ItemArray[colInx].ToString())

Comment: Just a suggestion - compile regex once, an then just call Replace method. This will increase performance.

static Regex regexReplaceHex = new Regex("[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x26]", RegexOptions.Compiled);

static string ReplaceHexadecimalSymbols(string txt)
{
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt))
   return regexReplaceHex.Replace(txt, string.Empty);
}

Answer (score 1):

x26 is the ampersand '&' character - this can be encoded with '&' so that it appears in your excel sheet.